# Finite Ramsey theorem in arithmetic

Tags: logic, proof-theory, ramsey-theory

How much induction is needed to prove finite Ramsey theorem in PA?

I searched for a while but in vain.

Comment: These [slides](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~chongct/RamseyTalk2.pdf) might be relevant.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Those slides treat the **infinite** Ramsey theorem, and are not in fact relevant (incidentally, the "google-noise" iRT creates is what's hindered the OP's search). This is very different: RCA$_0$ + infinite Ramsey's theorem for two-colorings of triples (= $RT^3_2$) is equivalent to ACA$_0$. RCA$_0$ has first-order part $I\Sigma_1$, while ACA$_0$'s first-order part is all of PA, so this situation might give the impression that finite Ramsey's theorem uses the full strength of PA. But that's completely wrong - see my answer.

Comment: (Indeed, we *know* it's wrong right from the get-go: PA isn't finitely axiomatizable, finite Ramsey's theorem is a single sentence in the language of arithmetic, and the proof of a single sentence can only use finitely many axioms. So once we know that finite Ramsey's theorem is provable in PA, we know that it must be provable in some fragment $I\Sigma_n$ without doing any work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$I\Sigma_1$ - the ordered semiring axioms plus induction for $\Sigma_1$ formulas - is certainly enough. [The standard proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem) goes through unchanged in $I\Sigma_1$, the key points being:

- The reduction to the two-color case is trivial.
- The formula we apply induction to in the two-color case is "There is some $n$ such that any $2$-coloring of the $s$-element subsets of $\{0,...,n\}$ has a homogeneous set of size $r$." This goes through in $I\Sigma_1$ (note that there's only one truly unbounded quantifier here, since the number of $s$-element subsets and $2$-colorings of $s$-element subsets of $\{0,...,n\}$ is bounded by a function whose totality is provable in $I\Sigma_1$).

But we can do better: by proving a stronger result (the exponential upper bound) we get rid of that unbounded quantifier. So $I\Delta_0+exp$ is already enough.

---

I believe this is treated in more detail in Hajek/Pudlak, [Metamathematics of first-order arithmetic](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235421926) (and even if it's not I strongly recommend that book, it's wonderful).

Comment: Excellent, thank you.